# Delay commands via bluetooth

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I have program which comunicate with bluetooth chip.

But I need send

```
(Send: "$$$"                           Receive: "CMD"    
Send: "S&,0404\r"                       Receive: "AOK"   
Send: "S&,0400\r"                      Receive: "AOK"    
Send: "---\r"                          Receive: "END")
```

I write Byte

```
 public void Zapis(String send) {
    String editText = send ;
    String tempHex = "";
    byte bytes[] = editText.getBytes();

    try {
        if (outputStream != null) {
            synchronized (obj2) {
                outputStream.write(bytes);
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                    getResources().getString(R.string.wait),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, ">>", e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and call this method..

```
Zapis("$$$");
    //Here I need DELAY command because now they come together in ONE command and  it's wrong 
    Zapis("S&,0404\r");
    //
    Zapis("S&,0400\r");
    //
    Zapis("---\r");
```

I thing so ,I need something like asleep or sleep for some milisecond, no? 
Or thise problem have someone simply solution.

If you have similar problem how it solve you?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an Sleep after each command..

```
Zapis("$$$");
Thread.sleep(100L);//100 ms delay
Zapis("S&,0404\r");
Thread.sleep(100L);//
Zapis("S&,0400\r");
Thread.sleep(100L);//
Zapis("---\r");
Thread.sleep(100L);
```